# Crossrider ajax requests does not automatically send cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, crossrider

In background.js I am sending a POST request to my Rails backend. However, cookies related to the backend (session cookies already stored using a logged in tab) are not being sent along with the request. The server cannot authenticate due to the missing cookies.
Shouldn't Crossrider automatically match cookies and send them along ajax requests?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [appAPI.request.post](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request-method-post) method in the background scope does not send cookie session information. I have forwarded your suggestion to the product team for consideration in future releases.

In the meantime, you might consider sending the authentication credentials in the body of the request.

Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: I ended up sending a message toAllTabs where the extension.js  actually attaches the session cookie automatically. However, I had to read the CSRF token generated by the Rails server for each request.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear you found a solution, though instead of sending to all tabs, you can be more efficient and use [appAPI.message.toActiveTab](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message-method-toActiveTab).